# >Is this always true that Re[$\int$ $w(t)dt$ ]$=$ $\int$ $Re[w(t)]$ $dt$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

> Let $w$ be a complex valued function over an interval $ a \leq t \leq b$.That is $w : [a,b] \to \mathbb C$
>
> Is this always true that
> \begin{align}
> \text{Re}\left[\int_a^b w(t)\, dt \right] &= \int_a^b \text{Re}[w(t)]\, dt,
> \end{align}
> where $\text{Re}[w(t)]$ means real part of $w(t)$?

Comment: Well what's the *definition* of the integral on the left?

Answer (score 0):

yes this is always true, same goes for the imaginary part.
This is because the only operation on the imaginary part or the real part once it is converted to the polar form to simplify integration is a rotation in the complex
plane.The real and imaginary cannot interact with each other otherwise hence the integral $\int_a^b cos(P(x)dx)=Re(\int_a^b exp(P(x))dx , \int_a^b sin(P(x))dx) = Im(\int_a^b exp(P(x))dx)$.

Comment: This is a correct answer to the literal question. It would be a much better answer if you [edit] it to show why. That need not be a formal proof. An explanation of the idea behind the argument would do.

Comment: More enlightening would be to say *why* it is true, does it rest on some deep theorem, easy lemma, or is it true by definition?

Answer (score 0):

We know that

$w(t) = u(t) + iv(t)$ [Since $w$ is a complex valued function]  thus

$\int_a^b w(t)\, dt$ =$\int_a^b u(t)\, dt$ $+$ $i$$\int_a^b v(t)\, dt$

And hence

\begin{align}
\text{Re}\left[\int_a^b w(t)\, dt \right] &= \int_a^b \text{Re}[w(t)]\, dt,
\end{align}

Thank you Torsten Schoeneberg